# Format link in string to open it in browser in Flex mobile project

Tags: regex, apache-flex, browser, mobile, textarea

I get Strings from a server that look something like this:

```
This is normal text followed by a link;
http://www.google.com
Links might also look like this;
http://google.com/whatever
```

This Strings are set as the text value in a spark TextArea. What I'd like to achieve is that
A. the text gets highlighted and
B. the user can click it and it opens in the systems browser.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: Using the StyleableTextField throws a typerror on Flex 4.6.
I tried the simplest HTML text like this;

```
StyleableTextField(newsStoryArea.textDisplay).htmlText = "TextArea <b>bold</b>￼<i>italic</i>."
```

which throws;

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText@fc3d0a1 to 
spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField.
```

Edit:
Nice one Adobe!
"htmlText in mobile skins

You cannot use the htmlText property in mobile applications."

On the same page (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS19f279b149e7481c698e85712b3011fe73-7fff.html#WS19f279b149e7481c7c94ce7c12b30152f48-7ffc), they say not to use TLF in mobile skins, so htmlText doesn't work, and TLF shouldn't be used.
Basically the two only options (unless there's a third one I don't know about) to format links properly are not to be used on mobile devices. Great!

Any recommendations?

Comment: You mean you want to generate `<a href="thelink">thetext</a>` or similar?

Comment: That would be the first step, which I'd solve using a regular expression. However, developing for mobile devices I'm after the fastest solution. The second step would be to open those links in the devices' browser, which I'm not sure is automatically supported in a TextArea.

Comment: I know that you can use the StyleableTextField to add an eventListener that supports links, however there seems to be a bug with that in Flex 4.6 as the cast from textArea to StyleableTextField doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it throw

```
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert
spark.components.supportClasses::StyleableStageText@fc3d0a1 to 
spark.components.supportClasses.StyleableTextField.
```

then your component use default skin which use StyleableStageText. And it not support htmlText property.

Based on name of your component "newsStoryArea" I can suppose that this is spark.components.TextArea. There are two mobile skins for spark.components.TextArea - default (I not remember its full name) and spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin. Class spark.skins.mobile.TextAreaSkin use StyleableTextField which have htmlText property. So you can specify that your text area component use this skin. In result you will able use htmlText.

Also if textDisplay will be nonselectable then textDisplay will not dispath TextEvent.LINK (if you need this).

Answer (score 1):

You may use `TextFlow`:

```
textArea.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow("<a href='http://www.google.com'>This is normal text followed by a link;<br/>http://www.google.com</a>", TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
```

Comment: Cheers mate, unfortunately I can't get anything out from that function but an empty String. I'm using Flex 4.6 btw.